# Splash screen in Blackberry qml cascade with time of 2 seconds

Tags: blackberry-10

Well, moving from android to blackberry cascade qml coding.

I want to add splash screen manually in qml with a time limit of 2-3 seconds.

How can I achieve this as there re no options related to time in qml.

On searching over web and developers forum nothing is revealed for this case.

**Help! Help! Help!**

This is my main.qml

```
import bb.cascades 1.0
import bb.myTimer 1.0 //error unknown library bb.myTimer


Page  
{
Container {
    layout: DockLayout {
    }
    onCreationCompleted: {
        myTimer.start();
    }

    ImageView {
        id: mImageViewIcon
        horizontalAlignment: HorizontalAlignment.Fill
        verticalAlignment: VerticalAlignment.Fill
        imageSource: "asset:///splash1.png"
    }

    attachedObjects: [
        QTimer {        //error : The QTimer component might be an unknown or custom       component. Its properties are not validated.
            id: myTimer
            interval: 3000
            onTimeout: {
                //Push New Page here

              mysheet1.open();


            }
        },

        Sheet 
        {
           id: mysheet1
           peekEnabled: false
           Page 
           {
              Container 
               {
                   background: Color.Transparent


                    ImageView 
                    {
                        horizontalAlignment: HorizontalAlignment.Fill
                        verticalAlignment: VerticalAlignment.Fill
                        imageSource: "asset:///splash2.png"
                    }


             }
        }
      }     
    ]
  }
}
```

My main.cpp

```
#include <bb/cascades/Application>

#include <QLocale>
#include <QTranslator>

**#include <Qtimer>**

#include "applicationui.hpp"

#include <Qt/qdeclarativedebug.h>

using namespace bb::cascades;

Q_DECL_EXPORT int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
Application app(argc, argv);

**qmlRegisterType<QTimer>("my.timer", 1, 0, "QTimer");**

// Create the Application UI object, this is where the main.qml file
// is loaded and the application scene is set.
new ApplicationUI(&app);

// Enter the application main event loop.
return Application::exec();
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you need to import timer as "import my.timer 1.0" , not "import bb.myTimer 1.0"

Comment: you can find more details here "http://kunalmaemo.blogspot.kr/2012/12/using-timer-with-bb10-cascade-qml-code.html"

Answer (score 2):

There is option for splash in `bar-descriptor.xml`

Open `bar-descriptor.xml` >> Select Tab `"Application"`

[You can see `Splash Screens:` box at right side. Select your splash screen.](http://developer.blackberry.com/native/documentation/cascades/getting_started/tools/configuration.html#applicationpage)

If you want to manually then follow below code.

Applied splash screen as imageview in page & use Timer. 
Push new page when Timer's time out.

Here is sample code of Timer.

```
import bb.cascades 1.0
import my.timer 1.0
Page {
    Container {
        layout: DockLayout {
        }
        onCreationCompleted: {
            mTimer.start();
        }
        ImageView {
            id: mImageViewIcon
            horizontalAlignment: HorizontalAlignment.Fill
            verticalAlignment: VerticalAlignment.Fill
            imageSource: "asset:///images/splash.png"
        }
        attachedObjects: [
            QTimer {
                id: mTimer
                interval: 2000
                onTimeout: {
                    //Push New Page here
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

**Don't forgot to add below line in main.cpp**

```
qmlRegisterType<QTimer>("my.timer", 1, 0, "QTimer");
```

Comment: The thing which you told abour bar descriptor file, I know about it. The disadvantage there is we can add only 1 image as a splash screen and on run it shows almost less than a second or just a second. My boss he wants me to keep 2 splash screens one by one and wants them to wait for atleast 3 seconds each. ufff...  Do you think the above code will work? because I saw and read in blackberry officail documentation that we need to create timer.hpp header file and timer.cpp file with some code to use QTimer. Here's the link . Do check it out once.

Comment: link :  http://developer.blackberry.com/native/documentation/cascades/dev/signals_slots/signals_slots_create_ui.html

Comment: well i will try on monday as tomorrow is sunday.. please be in touch regarding this issue and even future issues.as you know i'm just a begginer and there is no good support for bb-10 on web. well thanks . let me try once

Comment: I have edited my post with the code implementation . Please see and suggest some trick

Comment: while debugging its showing:: Spla debug 192.168.254.128 [BlackBerry C/C++ Application] 
 <terminated, exit value: -1>F:\bbndk\host_10_1_0_238\win32\x86\usr\bin\ntox86-gdb.exe 
 <terminated, exit value: -1>Spla on 192.168.254.128 pid 540446867 (10/4/13 8:50 AM)

Comment: while run :: CS Debugging enabled: false 
bb::cascades::QmlDocument: error when loading QML from:   QUrl( "asset:///main.qml" )  
--- errors:  (asset:///main.qml:2:1: module "bb.myTimer" is not installed) 
bb::cascades::QmlDocument:createRootObject document is not loaded or has errors, can't create root

Comment: in main.qml near import of myTimer its showing unknown library bb.myTimer    and the place where i am implementing its showing The Qtimer properties are not validated.

Comment: http://kunalmaemo.blogspot.kr/2012/12/using-timer-with-bb10-cascade-qml-code.html, this code shows, how to use Timer with BB10 App

Comment: hey kunal where i need to regiter the export .  i mean the exact plce in main.cpp

Answer (score 1):

As at the time of my answer, Momentics is at version 2.0. In this version of Momentics, there is no need for a QML for the splash screen.

To add a splash screen to your app, open the `bar-descriptor.xml` file. On the right hand side, below the icon specification, choose an image to be used as your splashscreen image.

That is all.

Rebuild and run and enjoy

Answer (score 0):

Try to use an animation as `TranslateTransition` and set duration to wait second.

Code:

```
attachedObjects: [
TranslateTransition {
    id: splashScreen
    duration: 2000 //wait in milliseconds
    onEnded: {
        //here the code to close splash screen        
    }
}]
```

and use `splashScreen.play(); //add this in onCreationComplete()` on an object as container or imageview, not `Page` or `NavigationPane` to start timer of splashscreen.